# Why does the SEARCH function works only in combination with SUMPRODUCT when searching for multiple strings?

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, sumproduct

I'm checking in Excel if a text in a cell in a column is within the text at another column.

Example text to search:

Column A

```
 1. a
 2. b
 3. c
```

Text to search within:

Column B

```
 1. aagg
 2. hgjk
 3. dhhd
 4. bahj
 5. adjd
```

This formula works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$1:A$3,B1)))
```

But this one works only for the first cell and for the rest I get #VALUE! error:

```
={(SEARCH(A$1:A$3,B1))}
```

Column B

- aagg -> 1
- hgjk -> #VALUE!
- dhhd -> #VALUE!
- bahj -> empty cell
- adjd -> empty cell

Also the second formula is only giving results for the first three cells, as many as the number of cells in column A. The last two are empty.

What makes SEARCH work with SUMPRODUCT but cannot work alone as an array formula?

Comment: So you want Excel to sum the amount of cells in column B that include the value from column A. So for cell A1, the answer you looking for would be 3? Or do you want to know how many of the values in A column are included in the text of B column?

Comment: No, no sum. I want to check if the values in column B includes any of the values in column A. The SUMPRODUCT gives 1 if value is in B, and 0 if not. So it will be 1,0,0,1,1. But the SEARCH alone, gives 1 only for the first cell and VALUE error for the next two, and nothing for the last two values in column B. I want to know why SEARCH alone doesn't work.

Comment: Dragging down your 2nd formula gives me 1, #VALUE, #VALUE, 2,1. For the 2nd and 3th value, the SEARCH won't find anything and returns a #VALUE, hence why there is a ISNUMBER in front of that function. It's not like SEARCH and SUMPRODUCT would work without the ISNUMBER. That's the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we have the following data...

```
A1:A3

    a
    b
    c

B1

    oboe
```

In this case, SEARCH(A$1:A$3,B1) returns the following array of values...

```
#VALUE!
2
#VALUE!
```

If the formula is entered in a single cell, only the first value from this array gets transferred to this cell.  So, in this case, #VALUE! will be display in the cell.

However, if you select three cells, then enter the formula, and then confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, all three values from the array gets transferred to these cells.

Note, though, since A1:A3 is a vertical range of cells, you'll need to select a vertical range of cells in which to return these values.  For example, you could select D1:D3, then while these three cells are selected enter the formula, and then confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Now, for the interesting part.  To return TRUE or FALSE, you'll need to first pass the array of values returned by SEARCH to ISNUMBER, and then you'll need to pass the array of values returned by ISNUMBER to the OR function, which in turn will return TRUE if at least one of the values returned by ISNUMBER is TRUE.  Otherwise, it returns FALSE.  So, you would use the following formula, which needs to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$1:A$3,B1)))
```

Here's how the formula is evaluated...

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$1:A$3,B1)))

=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"a";"b";"c"},"oboe")))

=OR(ISNUMBER({#VALUE!;2;#VALUE!}))

=OR({FALSE;TRUE;FALSE})
```

...which returns TRUE.  By the way, ISNUMBER is needed here.  We can't simply pass the array of values returned by SEARCH to the OR function.  If we did, the OR function would return #VALUE!, since the array of values contains an error value, in this case #VALUE!.  That's why we use ISNUMBER, so that any error value gets converted to FALSE before passing it the OR function.  So the OR function will always get an array of values made up of TRUE and/or FALSE.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Nice to see that OR formula gives similar result with SUMPRODUCT, will be useful. Going back to the SEARCH(A$1:A$3,B1) entered as an array formula, does it work if you have more values in column B? For me it doesn't. It only checks  'a' from column A. It doesn't check if b or c is in the values of column B (if there are more values there). This is confusing me a lot, why SEARCH works with OR and SUMPRODUCT but not alone.

Comment: As mentioned, SEARCH returns an array of values.  So these values need to go somewhere.  They can either be transferred to the worksheet or they can be passed to another function.  If you want to transfer them to the worksheet, you'll need to select the relevant number of cells in which the array values will be returned, as described earlier.  Or, if you want to pass them to a function, you either pass them to one that also returns an array of values (ie. ISNUMBER), or to one that returns a single result (ie. OR).

Comment: I understand now. Hey, thanks for the detailed answer! I could not 'get' it until I changed 'oboe' to 'aboe'. Then I got 1,2, value. Your comment about 'transferred to the worksheet' was my aha moment. Nice!

Comment: That's great, glad I could help.  Cheers!